# Why does a batch script TortoiseSVN update command fail when the repository isn't local?

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn

Here's my batch script:

```
    @echo off

cls
set SOURCE=svn://vcrep/UXP/ercpac/trunk/
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
echo. ++ Done.

echo. -- Cleaning up...
set SOURCE=
set SVN=
echo. ++ Done.
```

Unfortunately, this breaks for some odd reason. I have no problems pulling from this repository using the normal TortoiseSVN context menu. Specifically the error in the update dialog says:

> 'svn://vcrep/UXP/ercpac/trunk/' is not a local path

Perhaps there was something I'm not able to find in the TortoiseSVN docs that explains this?

Comment: I suggest that you use a command-line client (such as [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)) in your scripts. It can be used interchangeably with Tortoise SVN as long as major versions (1.6 or 1.7) match.

Comment: I was actually considering that, so I think I will. I'd still like to know why this isn't working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the documentation about [Automating Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics), the `/path` parameter indicates the local path to your **working copy**, not the URL of the repository.

Comment: ...
Ah. That's more than slightly embarrassing. Thanks!